# Is it possible to edit only one control in DataGridTemplateColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have done some research but did not find an answer for my question. There it is: I have a DataGridTemplateColumn which takes a StackPanel and two TextBlocks inside. I want to be able to edit one of the TextBlock only, is it possible?

there is my code:

```
    <DataGrid Name="gdProducts"
              MinHeight="100" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              GridLinesVisibility="None"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <!-- other columns -->

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Waiting Period"
                                IsReadOnly="False"
                                Width="80">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WaitingPeriod}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" days"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The way the code is written I will edit both TextBlocks (whole StackPanel). That is not I want.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Sorry for my mistake, actually my code above does not allow me to edit anything at all. I thought the IsReadOnly set to False would allow it to be editable like the others DataGrid Column types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use TextBox instead of TextBlock to the property you want to edit:

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.WaitingPeriod}"/>
         <TextBlock Text=" days"/>
   </StackPanel>
```

The RelativeSource is taking you up the visual tree to DataGrid, and the DataGrid DataContext is your ViewModel and this is why you have Access to WaitingPeriod propery.

Comment: Thanks Rom, this works. In addition to your answer, I would suggest to add **BorderThickness="0"** property to the TextBox in order to match the TextBlock template.